# Inferring depth from a front facing camera using Deep Reinforcement Learning, ConvNets and RNN's

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, reinforcement-learning

For a personal project I thought about a Pi Car that drives forward in a loop between the living room and kitchen and is able to steer itself between hallways and avoid collisions.

I was able to create this PoC using Behavioral Cloning.  I manually drove the RC car along a black line on the floor while it recorded images.

I then ran the images through a ConvNet and used the model to predict the left and right motor controls. [It worked](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipMzPTn735ZSWXyE8CeOIzTejO970srFEcVIdnsX9ioIH4GpyKHycxvZmfWqgSF7Mg?key=SDZHTTVkaDZGZUpxakF6YUgzS2NhUGpQWnpOMllB), but left a lot to be desired.

Now I would like to repeat this PoC without manual training.  A sonar sensor / LiDAR would work to avoid collision, but I am hoping to learn more about `CV`

The approach I have in mind is:

```
1) have the car in continuous forward motion while it records images
2) feed the images into a ConvNet to learn features like how close an object is
3) feed the output of the ConvNet into an RNN
4) the RNN will guide a reinforcement policy
5) the policy is simple: anything blocking your forward motion should be avoided
```

This is loosely based on this work at [Samsung and UC](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.08936.pdf).  My thinking is the features learned from the CNN will be used by the RNN in a time series to learn how close an object is.

Think of the car moving closer and closer to the couch.  The features of the couch will change; thus hopefully inferring depth.  Blocked forward motion would mean objects are getting closer.

One of the issues at now is how can I reflect `being blocked by objects` in the policy outside of a simulator?

In a ROS simulator it would be easy, since Gazebo gives you `x,y` coordinates and I can set a rate of change as good forward motion vs. being blocked.

But how can I do this on a physical robot that has no localization?

Also I am not enrolled in any classes and have been following free online material for the last year for all of this. Any critique, feedback and discussion is highly needed!